# Defect on email subscriptions Subscribe button on Mobile Safari

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, mobile-safari

**Problem:**
Using Mobile Safari, the Subscribe button for email subscription gets pressed, but it doesn't create the subscription.

**Expected:**
The Subscribe button would redirect you to the confirmation/success page.

**Repro on iPhone Mobile Safari:**

1. Log into the careers.stackoverflow.com site
2. Perform a search for a location. Mine was "Kelowna BC". 
   https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/subscribe?location=Kelowna%2c+BC%2c+Canada&range=100&distanceUnits=Miles
3. Click the link for "Subscribe to these search criteria by email"
4. The subscription currently doesn't exist yet (i.e. not a duplicate)
5. Click the orange `subscribe` button.
   The animation of down-press occurs, but the page doesn't navigate away to the next step.

Environment

- iOS 8.1.1
- iPhone 5

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was indeed a bug on mobile safari, it should be all good now.

You might need to refresh the page to benefit from the fix.

Thank you for your report!